# generate child pom dynamically

Tags: xslt, maven

I have been wondering if it is possible to generate child poms dynamically (via XSLT or something similar) based upon a kind of feature model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_model).

Comment: Your question is simply too vague.  Can you give a more concrete question?  And, do you really mean child POMs or POMs for modules in a multi-module project?  You should understand that POM inheritance and aggregation can be independent in Maven

Comment: Hi @Adrian, I meant preferably child poms being created while processing the parent pom. I learn though that this is not possible!

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want them to be part of the reactor build.

The reactor (list of all projects and the plugins to run against them) must be complete and deterministic before any plugins start running.

This is why property substitution in (XPath) `/project/parent/groupId`, `/project/parent/artifactId`, `/project/parent/version`, `/project/groupId`, `/project/artifactId`, and `/project/version` are not permitted, as that would lead to a non-deterministic build plan.

However, if you want to create a bunch of projects via XSLT and then in a subsequent reactor (read Maven invocation) do stuff with them, that would work.

You could use [Mojo's XML Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) to do the XSLT for you and then use the [Maven Invoker Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) to fork a new reactor but you will be in a sort half-way house and stuck with the lifecycle phases that you configure invoker with.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Stephen, this is probably the way I should go